# How to install tensorflow-1.12.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl on Windows 10 running i7 64 bit processor

Tags: tensorflow, installation

I am trying to take an online course that requires me to install tensorflow. According to pyPI tensorflow only runs under 64 bit environments. I have 3.6 (64 bit) and 3.7 (64 bit) installed on a Windows 10 device running an i7 processor. pip install tensorflow-1.12.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl returns a '...is not a supported wheel on this platform' under both 3.6 and 3.7 environments.

Interestingly, thought I have updated pip to 19.0.1 (at least it says it successfully did so), I am still getting the message that I need to upgrade my pip version.

Answer (score 0):

### This is what you are looking for.

Make sure you have updated pip first to enable wheel support:

> pip install --upgrade pip

and then:

> pip install C:/some-dir/tensorflow-1.12.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using anaconda and install TensorFlow in an conda environment. This will capsulate your online course from the rest of your system and is quite a good habit when working with multiple projects.